# Select command using like condition

Tags: sql, select, sql-like

How to use select statement using like condition by passing a column from another table?

My query

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM COMPANYNAME_RESTRICT_LIST a,itaukei_data_store_key b 
WHERE 
   b.surname LIKE a.company_name%  OR 
   b.surname LIKE %a.company_name% OR
   b.surname LIKE %a.company_name% OR
   b.surname LIKE a.company_name%;
```

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: are those ORs part of sql query or part of question?

Comment: Its a part of my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works Fine.

```
SELECT * 
FROM COMPANYNAME_RESTRICT_LIST a,itaukei_data_store_key b 
WHERE b.surname LIKE '%'||a.company_name||'%' or 
    b.surname LIKE '%'||a.company_name or 
    b.surname LIKE a.company_name||'%' or 
    b.surname LIKE a.company_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

concatenation: +'%'

```
SELECT 
  count(1) 
FROM 
  COMPANYNAME_RESTRICT_LIST a,
  itaukei_data_store_key b 
WHERE       
  b.surname LIKE '%'+a.company_name+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL function is `concat()`:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM COMPANYNAME_RESTRICT_LIST a join
     itaukei_data_store_key b 
     on b.surname like concat('%', a.company_name, '%')
```

Not all databases support `concat()`.  So, one of the following will also generally work:

```
     on b.surname like '%' || a.company_name || '%'
     on b.surname like '%' + a.company_name + '%'
     on b.surname like '%' & a.company_name & '%'
```